# AppleScript hotkey repeat

Tags: macos, applescript

How can I change this AppleScript from sending the <kbd>r</kbd> key 100 times to instead repeat the keypress while being held down?

```
activate application "World of Warcraft"
repeat 100 times
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "r" using command down
    delay 0.5
end repeat
```

Comment: This isn't possible with vanilla AppleScript. You could simulate a keypress-and-hold using Objective-C (I've done similar stuff for mouse events), but I don't know how stable it would be, or if AppleScript is the best tool for this.

Comment: Thanks Ted. I am trying to find anything that will run on my m1 mac mini that will do what im looking for. Im unable to find anything that can do an auto hotkey. This is what i used 

{
$r::
   Loop  
   {
    if not GetKeyState("r", "P")
      break
     Send r
     Sleep 40
    }
return
}

Comment: Hah! I don't even recognize that language. I can work it in python using PyObjc; would that be useful to you?

Comment: Im not sure. I don't know much beyond how it worked on windows using autohotkey.

Comment: im willing to pay a dev to get this to work